# How am I meant to loop through a set of DOM elements within a Polymer 1.0 Element?

Tags: javascript, foreach, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to loop through a set of static paper-checkbox elements, but my code is failing with:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function"

The relevant line of code is:

```
this.querySelectorAll('paper-checkbox').forEach(function(cb) {
```

I'm sure it's me being dumb - but what am I doing incorrectly in either selecting and/or iterating through the selected (static) checkboxes?

I'm effectively looking for the Polymer 1.0 alternative to JQuery's .each() function.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  I've just found the solution [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html).

Instead of:

```
this.querySelectorAll()
```

I should have been using:

```
Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll()
```

Works perfectly now!

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `this.querySelectorAll('paper-checkbox')` returns a NodeList, not an Array. They looks similar but they are different.
NodeList doesn't have the method `foreach` on its prototype.

An easy solution is to convert your Nodelist to Array like this:
`Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('paper-checkbox'))`

I suggest you to read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) in MDN on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
this.querySelector('paper-checkbox')
```

is null.

I think you need to go into the shadow root to get the elements e.g.

```
 this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('paper-checkbox')
```

added:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('paper-checkbox').array().forEach(function(cb) {
```

Comment: Hi pmo.

shadowRoot is null too, so querySelectorAll is failing with (Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null). - Good catch on that I had querySelector rather than querySelectAll.  Still having the same issue though.

Comment: sorry you need to add .array() too I'll edit above answer fully

Comment: When are you calling the forEach function? If it is called before the element is put into the dom the result maybe null, thats all I can think off?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** You need to use `dom-repeat`.

---

According to the [API documentation here](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/):

> *"The dom-repeat element is a custom HTMLTemplateElement type extension that automatically stamps and binds one instance of template content to each object in a user-provided array."*

---

**Example Code:**

```
<dom-module id="employee-list">
  <template>
    <div> Employee list: </div>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
      <div>First name: <span>{{item.first}}</span></div>
      <div>Last name: <span>{{item.last}}</span></div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'employee-list',
      ready: function() {
        this.employees = [{
          first: 'Bob',
          last: 'Smith'
        }, {
          first: 'Sally',
          last: 'Johnson'
        }, ...];
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Hi Mowzer.  I've edited my question for clarity.  The query isn't on how to loop through an array to generate dynamic content, it's on how to (via a javascript function) loop through a static set of checkboxes (or any element).  Thanks again.

Comment: @Miles: Perhaps I could be more helpful if you could provide some more context? For example, can you post the code for your entire element? I'm guessing you are writing this within an element? Or are you? And also, why are you trying to loop thru the checkboxes? What is your end goal?